# How to add ngclass dynamically on the basis of correct or wrong answer in angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework

```
export class QuestionsPage implements OnInit {
  question = [];
  isAnswerd: boolean = false;
  wrong: boolean = false;
  qIndex: number = 0;
  indicatorlength = [];
  score: number = 0;
  min: number = 0;
  sec: any = 0;
  constructor(private service: AppServiceService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.question = this.service.question;
    this.renderIndicator();
    this.timeCount();
  }

  checkQuestion(ans) {
    console.log(ans.target.id);
    document.getElementById(ans.target.id).style.color = "white";
    document.getElementById(ans.target.id).style.backgroundColor = "red";
    const correctOption = this.question[this.qIndex].answer;
    if (ans == correctOption) {
      this.score++;
      this.isAnswerd = true;
      this.renderIndicator("correct", this.qIndex);
    } else {
      this.isAnswerd = true;
    }
  }

  nextQuestion() {
    document.getElementById("A").style.color = "black";
    document.getElementById("A").style.backgroundColor = "#cccccc";
    document.getElementById("B").style.color = "black";
    document.getElementById("B").style.backgroundColor = "#cccccc";
    document.getElementById("C").style.color = "black";
    document.getElementById("C").style.backgroundColor = "#cccccc";
    document.getElementById("D").style.color = "black";
    document.getElementById("D").style.backgroundColor = "#cccccc";
    this.isAnswerd = false;
    if (this.qIndex < this.question.length - 1) {
      this.qIndex++;
    } else {
    }
  }

  renderIndicator(ansType?: string, qIndex?: number) {
    const totalQuestions = this.question.length;
    for (let i = 0; i < totalQuestions; i++) {
      if (i < 9) {
        const a = i + 1;
        const num = "0" + a;
        this.indicatorlength.push(num);
      } else {
        this.indicatorlength.push(i + 1);
      }
      if (ansType == "correct") {
      } else {
      }
    }
  }

}
```

I want to change color when answer is right , use bg-primary class else bg-danger. How can I manage background color when user clicked answer ? NgClass directive in Angular to dynamically assign class names to specific index value  .
I want to change color when answer is right , use bg-primary class else bg-danger. How can I manage background color when user clicked answer ? NgClass directive in Angular to dynamically assign class names to specific index value

[image]

Answer (score 0):

the dynamic part would be *easier & much simpler* using something like -> [`Render2` lib](https://angular.io/api/core/Renderer2)

Following that, you can easily [add the `your special class` dynamically](https://angular.io/api/core/Renderer2#addClass) in the selected event

1. `import { Renderer2 } from '@angular/core';`
2. `constructor(private render:Renderer2) { }`
3. Handle your `selected event` or answer click like so

```
HandleCorrectAnswer(event:any) { 
     //this.renderer.addClass(event.target,"some selected answer NgClass here");

     this.renderer.addClass(event.target,"bg-primary");
     
     //... do something more
   }
```

---

In html:

```
<button class="yourDefaultClasses" (click)="HandleCorrectAnswer()">User Selected Answer</button>
```